# Incorrect syntax near 'ID",'Number','Station'

Tags: asp.net

I am unable to register the account getting

> incorrect syntax near 'ID",'Number','Station'

- Front end: ASP.NET
- Back end: SQL Server

My code:

```
protected void btnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        con.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] (Name, Mail ID, Password, Gender, Address, Select District, Pincode, Mobile Number, Qualification, Adhar Number, ID Proof, ID Proof Number, Select Nearest Police Station) 
                        VALUES (@name, @mailid, @password, @gender, @address, @selectdistrict, @pincode, @mobilenumber, @qualification, @adharnumber, @idproof, @idproofnumber, @selectnearestpolicestation)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mailid", email.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectdistrict", district.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", pincode.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobilenumber", mobnum.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qualification", qualification.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adharnumber", adharnum.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproof", idproof.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproofnumber", idproofnum.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectnearestpolicestation", policestation.SelectedItem.ToString());

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("User.aspx");
        Response.Write("Registration successful");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" +ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have named my table as table

Comment: In your insert statement you have the `select` words which are reserved keywords so you need to put `[]` brackets around it like `[Select]`

Comment: And please do the `con.Close()` *before* the `Response.Redirect`. Or better, enclose this code in a `using` block

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have column names in your insert query that contain a space - like "Mail ID", or "Mobile Number".

If you actually do have such columns in your table (really **bad** design choice which should be avoided!), then you **must** enclose those column names in square brackets - like this:

```
string query = 
    "INSERT INTO [Table] (Name, [Mail ID], Password, Gender, Address, 
                          [Select District], Pincode, [Mobile Number], Qualification, 
                          [Adhar Number], [ID Proof], [ID Proof Number],
                          [Select Nearest Police Station]) 
     VALUES (@name, @mailid, @password, @gender, @address, 
             @selectdistrict, @pincode, @mobilenumber, @qualification, 
             @adharnumber, @idproof, @idproofnumber, @selectnearestpolicestation)";
```

Also, using a T-SQL reserved keyword `Table` as a table or column name is another really bad naming choice - try to avoid this, it's just a recipe for trouble and headaches - and it's a very poorly chosen name, too, since it really doesn't convey ***what*** kind of data that table contains......

Comment: still I get an error invalid column name Mobile Number

Comment: @VivekN: well, **is there** really a column called "mobile number" (with a space) in your table?? You didn't show us the table structure (the SQL to create the table), so we cannot really diagnose such errors.....